# Gstreamer splitmuxsink resetting timestamp on split

Tags: performance, timestamp, gstreamer

I've been using splitmuxsink to split the recordings of a live video stream by length or by the "split now" cmd. The resulting video files are all timestamped with the "global time" from when the pipeline started.

File1 00:00 - 05:00

File2 05:00 - 10:00

File3 10:00 - 15:00

This is causing issues when playing back the files in certain video players that are expected a time stamp starting at 0.

What I'd like to do is reset the time stamping every time the recordings are split and a new file is started.

File1 00:00 - 05:00

File2 00:00 - 05:00

File3 00:00 - 05:00

Comment: I discovered that this can be achieved by setting async-finalize=True. Annoyingly I'm stuck using a older version of gstreamer that does not support his property.